# WordPress TinyMCE Editor plugin not copying values from input boxes into shortcode. Displaying VALUE="undefined" for each

Tags: javascript, wordpress, tinymce

I am building a custom plugin on WordPress to insert a [video_embed] shortcode with two attributes ("id" and "border"). The button for the TinyMCE editor that I have created is working but does not register the values. I have tried different ways of assigning the values to be passed but they do not work. The shortcode below is always returned as when I assign the variable 'returnText' as also shown. However I know this is not correct but in other methods I have tried no shortcode is returned:

> [video_embed id="undefined" border="undefined"]

```
var returnText = '\[video_embed id="' + win[0] + '" border="' + win[1] + '"\]';
```

Is there something I'm missing? My full code for the JS file for the button is below.

```
(function(){
  tinymce.create('tinymce.plugins.vidembedtinymceplugin', {
    init: function(ed, url){
      ed.addButton('vidembedbtn', {
        title: 'Video Embed',
        cmd: 'vidembedBtnCmd',
        image: url + '/video-btn.png'
      });
      ed.addCommand('vidembedBtnCmd', function(){
        var selectedText = ed.selection.getContent({format: 'html'});
        var win = ed.windowManager.open({
          title: 'Video Embed Properties',
          body: [
            {
              type: 'textbox',
              name: 'vidid',
              label: 'Video ID',
              minWidth: 500,
              value: ''
            },
            {
              type: 'textbox',
              name: 'border-color',
              plugins: "textcolor colorpicker",
              toolbar: "forecolor backcolor", 
              label: 'Border Color',
              minWidth: 500,
              value : ''
            },
          ],
          buttons: [
            {
              text: "Ok",
              subtype: "primary",
              onclick: function(v) {
            win.close();
            var returnText = '\[video_embed id="' + win[0] + '" border="' + win[1] + '"\]';   
            var open = '\[';
            var close = ']';
            ed.execCommand('mceInsertContent', 0, returnText);
          }
        },
        {
          text: "Skip",
          onclick: function() {
            win.close();
            var returnText = '' + selectedText + '';
            ed.execCommand('mceInsertContent', 0, returnText);
          }
        },
        {
          text: "Cancel",
          onclick: function() {
            win.close();
          }
        }
      ],
    onsubmit: function(e){
        var params = [];
        if( e.data.vidid.length > 0 ) {
          params.push('id="' + e.data.vidid + '"');
        }
        if( e.data.border-color.length > 0 ) {
          params.push('border="' + e.data.border-color + '"');
        }
        if( params.length > 0 ) {
          paramsString = ' ' + params.join(' ');
        }
        var returnText = '' + selectedText + '';
        ed.execCommand('mceInsertContent', 0, returnText);
      }
    });
  });
},
getInfo: function() {
  return {
    longname : 'Video Embed',
    author : 'Plugin Author',
    authorurl : 'https://www.axosoft.com',
    version : "1.0"
  };
}
});
tinymce.PluginManager.add( 'vidembedtinymceplugin', 
tinymce.plugins.vidembedtinymceplugin );
})();
```

Comment: Did my answer help you? If it doesn't work, let me know and I'll update the code.

Comment: @SallyCJ - yes, sorry. It worked very well. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome @ChrisBrosnan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, change *all* the `e.data.border-color` to `e.data['border-color']`!

The reason is because the key (which is `border-color`) contains a dash (`-`). But for more info, see the [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Objects_and_properties). (find the section that has "*any property name that is not a valid JavaScript identifier*")

### Now *here's how you can solve the "undefined" issue*:

1. The `onclick` value of the "Ok" button should be set to `submit`. So
   use this instead of what you currently have:

   ```
   {
     text: "Ok",
     subtype: "primary",
     onclick: 'submit'
   },
   ```
2. In the `onsubmit()` function, change this:

   ```
   if( params.length > 0 ) {
     paramsString = ' ' + params.join(' ');
   }
   var returnText = '' + selectedText + '';
   ```

   to this one:

   ```
   params = params.join(' ');
   var returnText = (params ? '\[video_embed ' + params + '\]' : '') +
       selectedText + '';
   ```

[Try a demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zLgewy/left?editors=1010#0)